# How to run C++ TCP/IP multithread server as deamon

Tags: c++, c, linux, tcp, systemd

I have a problem with running TCP/IP server as deamon in systemd.

I have a server as shown here: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#client-server-background
Every client has own process.

Server accept new client code:

```
    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener

            // some logic here
            // When the client receives a specific message, it ends. Of course I call close socket and exit with exit code 0.

            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }
```

Service:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=folder
ExecStart=binary -c config
Restart=always
```

The service is registered and I control it with `systemctl` command.

The problem is that the number of processes in my program is gradually growing after client connected.
When I run the server via command line, everything works.

Where should be the problem? Do systemd deamon need some specific configuration or client process needs to be terminated in another way?

Comment: It is your application's responsibility to terminate when it is done. systemd has no idea whatsoever, and couldn't possibly have any idea whatsoever, when your application has finished whatever it's supposed to do. For whatever reason, when started from systemd your application process doesn't terminate. You'll have to figure out why, only you have the full access to the source code, and can debug this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The application should never quit. It must listen to accept connections. The problem is running from command line vs systemd deamon. From command line it's working. I need advice if service is configured correctly or need to implement specific behaviour of systemd deamon to my code.

Comment: Well, something is starting your application. The shown systems service is fairly basic, and unless you found some kind of a bug in systemd you'll have to look for problems in your app.

Comment: Nitpick: you don't have a multithreaded server. You have a multi-process server. Nowadays it's easier (and often more efficient) to not fork but create threads instead. Anyway, just attach to the process that's supposed to be dead but isn't with `gdb` and inspect the active call stacks. Also the simple `ps` command can tell the status of the process, which is also quite useful.

Comment: That `accept` might not be the best sytemd design. The example you give is your basic 1980's design, but systemd has something called "socket activation". See http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html for details. You still have one process per client, but systemd sets up the socket for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reap your zombies. Simplest working reaper:

```
int ignored;
waitpid(-1, &ignored, WNOHANG);
waitpid(-1, &ignored, WNOHANG);
new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
```

This works because any accept only starts one new process, but we clean up two every time so the number of processes decreases every time around the loop. You will still see a few zombies but not too many. Typically only one.

More complex reapers can reduce the number of zombies to zero. `sigselect` can get the job done.

I do not recommend socket activation for stuff that's used much as that pays one `execve()` per connection and `execve()` is not fast.

Comment: You can have systemd socket activation with the listener socket as well, similar to inetd's `wait` mode, but extended to pass multiple listeners. I'd still not make my service reliant on any systemd interface though, because systemd is not portable to non-Linux systems.